# gradient under bezier cruve path Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphic

I need animate gradient under animated line like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/dmaz3/ with Raphael JS. How can I do that ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<script>
var paper = Raphael('canvas');
    var tt = paper.path("M -4.47059 261.467 L 5.52941 261.467 C 5.52941 261.467 12.4412 250.867 17.049 250.867 C 21.6569 250.867 23.9608 250.867 28.5686 250.867 C 33.1765 250.867 35.4804 250.867 40.0882 250.867 C 44.6961 250.867 47 249.1 51.6078 247.333 C 56.2157 245.567 58.5196 243.8 63.1275 242.033 C 67.7353 240.267 70.0392 242.033 74.6471 238.5 C 79.2549 234.967 81.5588 213.767 86.1667 213.767 C 90.7745 213.767 93.0784 231.433 97.6863 231.433 C 102.294 231.433 104.598 219.067 109.206 219.067 C 113.814 219.067 116.118 236.733 120.725 236.733 C 125.333 236.733 127.637 220.48 132.245 212 C 136.853 203.52 139.157 194.333 143.765 194.333 C 148.373 194.333 150.676 201.4 155.284 201.4 C 159.892 201.4 162.196 185.5 166.804 185.5 C 171.412 185.5 173.716 190.8 178.324 190.8 C 182.931 190.8 185.235 185.5 189.843 185.5 C 194.451 185.5 196.755 185.5 201.363 185.5 C 205.971 185.5 208.275 219.387 212.882 194.333 C 227.49 159.28 219.794 195.64 244.402 170.233 L 244.402 261.467 z");
    tt.attr({
        'fill': '90-#429321-#B4EC51'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you "need" it in Raphael.js? Any javascript can run in a context where Raphael can run.

Comment: Yes ! I created elements in svg what raphael created, thz !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<svg height="300" version="1.1" width="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <clipPath
                    id="xxx">
                <rect x="0"
                      y="100"
                      width="250"
                      height="194"
                      transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">

                    <animate attributeName="width"
                             from="0"
                             to="250"
                             dur="2s"/>
                </rect>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <g clip-path="url('#xxx')">

            <path d="M -4.47059 261.467 L 5.52941 261.467 C 5.52941 261.467 12.4412 250.867 17.049 250.867 C 21.6569 250.867 23.9608 250.867 28.5686 250.867 C 33.1765 250.867 35.4804 250.867 40.0882 250.867 C 44.6961 250.867 47 249.1 51.6078 247.333 C 56.2157 245.567 58.5196 243.8 63.1275 242.033 C 67.7353 240.267 70.0392 242.033 74.6471 238.5 C 79.2549 234.967 81.5588 213.767 86.1667 213.767 C 90.7745 213.767 93.0784 231.433 97.6863 231.433 C 102.294 231.433 104.598 219.067 109.206 219.067 C 113.814 219.067 116.118 236.733 120.725 236.733 C 125.333 236.733 127.637 220.48 132.245 212 C 136.853 203.52 139.157 194.333 143.765 194.333 C 148.373 194.333 150.676 201.4 155.284 201.4 C 159.892 201.4 162.196 185.5 166.804 185.5 C 171.412 185.5 173.716 190.8 178.324 190.8 C 182.931 190.8 185.235 185.5 189.843 185.5 C 194.451 185.5 196.755 185.5 201.363 185.5 C 205.971 185.5 208.275 219.387 212.882 194.333 C 227.49 159.28 219.794 195.64 244.402 170.233 L 244.402 261.467">
            </path>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I found this solution without raphael ( with raphael can't find

Answer (score 0):

`"fill": "90-#429321-#B4EC51"`
where

- `90` - angle
- `#429321` - first color
- `#B4EC51` - second color

> Gradients Linear gradient format:
>   “‹angle›-‹colour›[-‹colour›[:‹offset›]]*-‹colour›”, example:
>   “90-#fff-#000” – 90° gradient from white to black or
>   “0-#fff-#f00:20-#000” – 0° gradient from white via red (at 20%) to
>   black.
>
> radial gradient: “r[(‹fx›,
>   ‹fy›)]‹colour›[-‹colour›[:‹offset›]]*-‹colour›”, example: “r#fff-#000”
>   – gradient from white to black or “r(0.25, 0.75)#fff-#000” – gradient
>   from white to black with focus point at 0.25, 0.75. Focus point
>   coordinates are in 0..1 range. Radial gradients can only be applied to
>   circles and ellipses.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<script>
var paper = Raphael('canvas');
    var tt = paper.path("M -4.47059 261.467 L 5.52941 261.467 C 5.52941 261.467 12.4412 250.867 17.049 250.867 C 21.6569 250.867 23.9608 250.867 28.5686 250.867 C 33.1765 250.867 35.4804 250.867 40.0882 250.867 C 44.6961 250.867 47 249.1 51.6078 247.333 C 56.2157 245.567 58.5196 243.8 63.1275 242.033 C 67.7353 240.267 70.0392 242.033 74.6471 238.5 C 79.2549 234.967 81.5588 213.767 86.1667 213.767 C 90.7745 213.767 93.0784 231.433 97.6863 231.433 C 102.294 231.433 104.598 219.067 109.206 219.067 C 113.814 219.067 116.118 236.733 120.725 236.733 C 125.333 236.733 127.637 220.48 132.245 212 C 136.853 203.52 139.157 194.333 143.765 194.333 C 148.373 194.333 150.676 201.4 155.284 201.4 C 159.892 201.4 162.196 185.5 166.804 185.5 C 171.412 185.5 173.716 190.8 178.324 190.8 C 182.931 190.8 185.235 185.5 189.843 185.5 C 194.451 185.5 196.755 185.5 201.363 185.5 C 205.971 185.5 208.275 219.387 212.882 194.333 C 227.49 159.28 219.794 195.64 244.402 170.233 L 244.402 261.467 z");
    tt.attr({
        "fill": "90-#429321-#B4EC51",
        "stroke-width": 0,
        "width": 20
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thz, but I need do this with animation, how in example in link http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/dmaz3/